# How are the following equivalent to O(N)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am reading an example where the following are equivalent to O(N):

```
 O(N + P), where P < N/2
 O(N + log N)
```

Can someone explain in laymen terms how it is that the two examples above are the same thing as O(N)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 1):

We always take the greater one in case of addition.

In both the cases N is bigger than the other part.

In first case `P < N/2 < N`

In second case `log N < N`

Hence the complexity is `O(N)` in both the cases.

Comment: A Big O algorithm is not measured by how fast it is but by how slow it is.

Comment: No one said anything about speed @ub3r

Answer (score 1):

> Let f and g be two functions defined on some subset of the real numbers. One writes
>
> f(x) = O(g(x)) as x -> infinite
>
> if and only if there is a positive constant M such that for all sufficiently large values of x, the absolute value of f(x) is at most M multiplied by the absolute value of g(x). That is, **f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if there exists a positive real number M and a real number x0 such that**
>
> **|f(x)| <= M |g(x)| for all x > x0**

So in your case 1:

```
f(N) = N + P <= N + N/2
```

We could set M = 2 Then:

```
|f(N)| <= 3/2|N| <= 2|N| (N0 could any number)
```

So:

```
N+p = O(N)
```

In your second case, we could also set M=2 and N0=1 to satify that:

```
|N + logN| <= 2 |N| for N > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

`Big O notation` usually only provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function, [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). Meaning for your both cases, as `P < N` and `logN < N`. So that `O(N + P) = O(2N) = O(N)`, The same to `O(N + log N) = O(2N) = O(N)`. Hope that can answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of understanding you can assume that `O(n)` represents that the complexity is of the [order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_polynomial) of n and also that `O` notation represents the upper bound(or the complexity in worst case). So, when I say that `O(n+p)` it represents that the order of n+p.

Let's assume that in worst case p = n/2, then what would be order of n+n/2? It would still be `O(n)`, that is, linear because constants do form a part of the Big-O notation.

Similary, for `O(n+logn)` because logn can never be greater than `n`. So, overall complexity turns out to be linear.

Answer (score 0):

**In short**

If N is a function and C is a constant:

`O(N+N/2)`:

```
If C=2, then for any N>1 :
    (C=2)*N > N+N/2,
    2*N>3*N/2,
    2> 3/2 (true)
```

`O(N+logN)`:

```
If C=2, then for any N>2 :
    (C=2)*N > N+logN,
    2*N > N+logN,
    2>(N+logN)/N,
    2> 1 + logN/N (limit logN/N is 0),
    2>1+0 (true)
```

Counterexample `O(N^2)`:

```
No C exists such that C*N > N^2 :
    C > N^2/N,
    C>N (contradiction).
```

**Boring mathematical part**

I think the source of confusion is that equals sign in `O(f(x))=O(N)` does not mean *equality*! Usually if x=y then y=x. However consider `O(x)=O(x^2)` which is true, but reverse is false: `O(x^2) != O(x)`!

`O(f(x))` is an *upper bound* of how fast a function is growing.
Upper bound is not an exact value.

If `g(x)=x` is an upper bound for some function `f(x)`, then function `2*g(x)` (and in general anything growing faster than `g(x)`) is also an upper bound for `f(x)`.

The formal definition is: for function `f(x)` to be bound by some other function `g(x)` if you chose any constant `C` then, starting from some `x_0` `g(x)` is always greater than `f(x)`.

`f(x)=N+N/2` is the same as `3*N/2=1.5*N`. If we take `g(x)=N` and our constant `C=2` then `2*g(x)=2*N` is growing faster than `1.5*N`:

If `C=2` and `x_0=1` then for any `n>(x_0=1)` `2*N > 1.5*N`.

same applies to N+log(N):

```
C*N>N+log(N)
C>(N+logN)/N
C>1+log(N)/N
...take n_0=2
C>1+1/2
C>3/2=1.5
```

use `C=2`: `2*N>N+log(N)` for any `N>(n_0=2)`,
e.g.

```
2*3>3+log(3), 6>3+1.58=4.68
...
2*100>100+log(100), 200>100+6.64
...
```

Now interesting part is: no such constant exist for `N` & `N^2`. E.g. `N squared` grows faster than `N`:

```
C*N > N^2
C > N^2/N
C > N
```

obviously no single constant exists which is greater than a variable. Imagine such a constant exists `C=C_0`. Then starting from `N=C_0+1` function N is greater than constant `C`, therefore such constant does not exist.

**Why is this useful in computer science?**

In most cases calculating exact algorithm time or space does not make sense as it would depend on hardware speed, language overhead, algorithm implementation details and many other factors.

`Big O` notation provides means to estimate which algorithm is better independently from real world complications. It's easy to see that O(N) is better than O(N^2) starting from some `n_0` no matter which constants are there in front of two functions.

Another benefit is ability to estimate algorithm complexity by just glancing at program and using `Big O` properties:

```
for x in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(C)
```

has complexity of `O(N)` and

```
for x in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(C_0)
    sub-calc with O(C_1)
```

still has complexity of `O(N)` because of "multiplication by constant rule".

```
for x in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(N)
```

has complexity of `O(N*N)=O(N^2)` by "product rule".

```
for x in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(C_0)
for y in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(C_1)
```

has complexity of `O(N+N)=O(2*N)=O(N)` by "definition (just take `C=2*C_original`)".

```
for x in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(C)
for x in range(N):
    sub-calc with O(N)
```

has complexity of `O(N^2)` because "the fastest growing term determines `O(f(x))` if `f(x)` is a sum of other functions" (see explanation in the mathematical section).

**Final words**

There is much more to `Big-O` than I can write here! For example in some real world applications and algorithms beneficial `n_0` might be so big that an algorithm with worse complexity works faster on real data.

CPU cache might introduce unexpected hidden factor into otherwise asymptotically good algorithm.

Etc...